# Initiate class multiple times, threading and csv

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, class

so I am trying to make automated script to buy limited alcohol, I coded it without the class and it works just fine but I cant code good error handling without class + code looks much better with them.

So the issue is that if I am running more than one thread it is basically running script multiple times in one class. How many threads I need to run depends how many lines I have in threads.csv + each line has different login and shipping info. Do you have any idea how to fix it? (would like to keep using threading since I learned it and I only know how to code some things with threading in final script)

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format= '[' + '%(asctime)s' + '] ' + '%(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')



class Zufanek():

    def main(self):

        with open('threads.csv', "r", encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as csvfile:
            tasks = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in tasks:
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.login, args=(line,)).start()



    def login(self, tasks):

        threadname = threading.currentThread().getName()
        threadname = str(threadname).replace('Thread-', 'TASK ')
        self.thread = '[' + str(threadname) + '] '

        self.email = tasks['EMAIL']
        self.password = tasks['PASSWORD']

        self.r = requests.Session()

        self.headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.3'
        }

        loginData = {
            'referer': '',
            'email': str(self.email),
            'password': str(self.password),
            'surname': ''
        }

        logging.info(f'''{self.thread}Logging in...''')

        loginResponse = self.r.post(url='https://www.lepsinalada.cz/action/Customer/Login/',
                               headers=self.headers, data=loginData)

        if loginResponse.url == 'https://www.lepsinalada.cz/klient/':
            logging.info(f'''{self.thread}Logged in successfuly!''')
        else:
            logging.info(f'''{self.thread}Login unsuccessful, check your credentials!''')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pico = Zufanek()
    pico.main()
```

Comment: ```import logging, threading, csv, requests, time```

Comment: You’ll have to have a class instance per thread - simplest way is to pull main out of the class and make it create an instance for every line of the csv.

Comment: And next time you put code in a question make sure it is a [mre] - include imports and everything needed (including some minimal data) needed to run your code. Imagine that someone reading your question needs to run your code - they need to be able to copy/paste your code into a file and _without adding anything_ run the code to see the problem you’re having.

Comment: Okay, sorry my bad! "simplest way is to pull main out of the class and make it create an instance for every line of the csv" - and how would you do this? :c @barny